# Prime numbers and remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am having trouble finding where to start with a formal proof of the following

We have this information:
$x, p \in \mathbb{N}$ 
p is a prime number. 
$gcd(x, p) = 1$
$T = \{1, 2, ... , p-1\}$ (positive integers less than p) 
$r_p(n)$ represents the remainder after p divides n

**Want to prove that $\{r_p(xa) | a \in T\} \subseteq T$**

I interpret the above as the set of remainders when $p$ divides $xa$ is a subset of T.

There have been hints to use this definition of prime: 
$Prime(p) : \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}, p\nmid a \land p \nmid b \Rightarrow p \nmid ab$

Any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Since the range of $r_p$ is $\{0,1,2,\ldots,p-1\}=\{0\}\cup T$, all you need to prove is that $r_p(xa)$ can never be $0$, given your conditions.

Comment: Not just for $a \in T$ for all integers relatively prime to $p$ (i.e. all $a$ so that $\gcd(a,p) = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The definition of remainder is [The remainder and quotient of $n$ when divided by $d$ are the unique integers $r$ and $q$ so that $n = q*d + r; 0 \le r < d$].

So by definition $r_p(n) \in \{0, 1,.....,p-1\}$.

So this question is equivalent $r_p(xa) \ne 0$.  That's all.

Note.  If $r_p(xa) = 0$ then $p|xa$.  If $r_p(xa) \ne 0$ then $p\not \mid xa$.

Now use your definition of prime.

(By the way, are you sure that was a *definition* rather than a basic proposition?  It goes either way but must text defines prime as a number with no factors other than $1$ and itself.  Which can be proven to be equivalent to your statement.)

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. And you are correct it was not exactly a definition for prime, but a proposition proven to be equivalent. I made an error

Comment: That's not really an error.  You *could* use that as a definition and then prove that if $p$ is prime then the only non-negative integers that divide $p$ are $1$ and $p$.  Any way, proposition or definition, you know it is true so you can use it.